# Base class type of the derived classes, Generics - .net

Tags: .net, generics, subclass

I read about contra and covariance problem and it looks like my code falls into that category. I just want to confirm whether i am doing something else wrong. I am using VS 2005 (company policy..)

I have a few classes as below:

```
entityBase{}
        entity1 : entityBase {}
        entity2 : entityBase {}
```

I have another set of classes as below:

```
dalBase<T> where T: entityBase {}
        entity1Dal : dalBase<entity1>{}
        entity2Dal : dalBase<entity2>{}
```

Now, I want to have a factory method to return the dal classes based on the parameter - like below:

```
public xxxType GetDalClass(pType) {
     if (pType == "1") return new entity1Dal();
     if (pType == "2") return new entity2Dal();
    }
```

My question: What should be the return type of this method - in other words, is there a common base class for entity1Dal and entity2Dal?

I tried dalbase and it did not work.

Thanks,
Saravana

Answer (score 2):

> is there a common base class for entity1Dal and entity2Dal?

Only `object`, really. One common way of getting round this is to split your `DalBase<T>` class in half - a generic type and a non-generic type which the generic type derives from:

```
public class DalBase
{
    // Any members which *don't* need to know about T
}

public class DalBase<T> : DalBase
{
    // T-specific members
}
```

Then you can change your method return type to the non-generic `DalBase` class.

Another option is to do the same sort of thing, but make the non-generic part an interface instead of a base class. The generic class would implement the interface *and* have T-specific members.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I used your suggestions and created the DalBase interface, without T specific members. 

I also added the "T" specific members to this interface - this time created those methods with **danger** variants instead of "T"(using VB.net).. And called the "T" specific methods from these methods. it works fine, even though not a good design..